# Example of an additive but non-linear functor

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, Mod$_A$ be the category of $A$-module. Is it possible for an additive functor $F:\text{Mod}_A\to\text{Mod}_A$ to be not $A$-linear? That is, can we find such $A$ and $F$ such that there is some $x\in A$ and $f:M\to N$ morphism between $A$-module, but $F(x.f)\ne x.F(f)$? I couldn't come up with any example. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\varphi:A\to B$ is any ring-homorphism then it induces a forgetful functor $F:\operatorname{Mod}_B\to\operatorname{Mod}_A$ which is additive.  Explicitly, given a $B$-module $M$, you make it into an $A$-module $F(M)$ using the scalar multiplication $a\cdot_{F(M)} m=\varphi(a)\cdot_Mm$.  If $B$ happens to be equal to $A$ but $\varphi$ is not the identity, then $F$ will fail to be $A$-linear.

(A concrete example of this that may be familiar is where $\varphi:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is complex conjugation, so $F$ is the functor on $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces that replaces the scalar multiplication on a vector space with its conjugate.)